# XNA 4.0 - Why does using a RenderTarget2d cause transparency on models?

Tags: xna, models, alpha

I have been working through Riemers ShadowMap tutorial and everything was going well until the section on drawing to a separate rendertarget. I am using a different model and quads but I assumed the process would still work.

If I draw the scene directly to the back buffer I get:
[image: Normal image]

When I draw it first to a RenderTarget2D and THEN to the screen, I get this weird transparent effect only on the model, the textured primitives below are still rendered fine:

[image: Weird transparency effect]

The RenderTarget is defined:

```
PresentationParameters pp = device.PresentationParameters;
renderTarget = new RenderTarget2D(device, pp.BackBufferWidth, 
           pp.BackBufferHeight, true, device.DisplayMode.Format, DepthFormat.Depth24);
```

And it is used in this way:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    device.SetRenderTarget(renderTarget);

    device.Clear(ClearOptions.Target | ClearOptions.DepthBuffer, Color.Black, 1.0f, 0);

    DrawScene("Simplest");

    device.SetRenderTarget(null);
    shadowMap = (Texture2D)renderTarget;

    device.Clear(ClearOptions.Target | ClearOptions.DepthBuffer, Color.DarkSlateBlue, 1.0f, 0);
    using (SpriteBatch sb = new SpriteBatch(device))
    {
        sb.Begin();
        sb.Draw(shadowMap, new Vector2(0, 0), null, Color.White, 0, new Vector2(0, 0), 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 1);
        sb.End();

    }
    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

What gives?

Edit 1:
I resolved the transparency effect by resetting:

```
device.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
device.BlendState = BlendState.Opaque;
```

But now the model has a purple tint on the side away from the light. Something to do with my Shader code I presume.

Edit 2:
Turns out the purple (blue) colour was a result of the window being cleared to .DarkSlateBlue and the RenderTarget having alpha transparency. 
Fixed with:

```
sb.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.Opaque);
```

Comment: If you've solved your problem, you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out:

```
device.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
device.BlendState = BlendState.Opaque;
```

But now the model has a purple tint on the side away from the light. Something to do with my Shader code I presume.

Turns out the purple (blue) colour was a result of the window being cleared to   .DarkSlateBlue and the RenderTarget having alpha transparency. Fixed with:

```
sb.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.Opaque);
```