# XNA 4.0 - Strange Behavior when using RenderTarget2D

Tags: xna-4.0, rendering, spritebatch, rendertargets

My Problem is similar to [XNA 4.0 - Why does using a RenderTarget2d cause transparency on models?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/55699/xna-4-0-why-does-using-a-rendertarget2d-cause-transparency-on-models).

I want to render my scene to a Texture2D and then draw the texture. 
If I set no RenderTarget at all (render directly to the back buffer), everything looks fine.

I draw my models/textures with:

```
graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack, BlendState.Opaque, SamplerState.AnisotropicClamp, DepthStencilState.Default, RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise);

[...Drawing methods for models etc. are called here...]

spriteBatch.End();
```

If I change that code to:

```
RenderTarget2D target = new RenderTarget2D(this.GraphicsDevice,this.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth,this.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight);
this.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(target);

graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack, BlendState.Opaque, SamplerState.AnisotropicClamp, DepthStencilState.Default, RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise);

[...Drawing methods for models etc. are called here...]

spriteBatch.End();
this.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
```

And render the texture / save it as an image-file, some objects get transparent and the drawing order changes sort of randomly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433791.aspx) do not state what kind of depth buffer and color buffer will be used using that overload. I suspect not explicitly specifiying a depth buffer is the issue here.

Try the [most complete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433785.aspx) constructor overload like this, and probably your problems will disappear:

```
new RenderTarget2D (
         this.GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice,
         this.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth,
         this.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight,
         true,
         SurfaceFormat.Color,
         DepthFormat.Depth16,
         4,
         RenderTargetUsage.DiscardContents
);
```